# How to change file permission of hello.sh file from Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, unix, child-process

I have this code written and want to run my `hello.sh` file from my node. it fails the error is

> error: Command failed: ./hello.sh > output.txt
> /bin/sh: 1: cannot create output.txt: Permission denied

How can I change the `permission` of `hello.sh` file to `executable`.

```
fs.chmod("hello.sh",0o777,(err)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
            return
        }
    })   
    exec("./hello.sh > output.txt", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
      console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
      return;
  }
  if (stderr) {
      console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
      return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

Comment: fs.chmod is async so you need to do the exec inside the callback

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
fs.chmod("hello.sh",0o777,(err)=>{
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  exec("./hello.sh > output.txt", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
      return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
      console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
      return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  });
});
```

You also need to make sure that the directory where hello.sh is running is writable.

Because the executed command is: `hello.sh > output.txt`

As the error message is: `cannot create output.txt: Permission denied`

it must not be writable.

Chmod the directory that contain hello.sh to make it writable, or change your exec command to: `./hello.sh > /tmp/output.txt`

Comment: I update my response

Answer (score 0):

When creating output files, first create them in `/tmp` to avoid these kind of issues. Then move them to where they need to go, re-read them to stream them async, etc.